# Prove function neither injective nor surjective

Tags: functions

Prove that the function $$f:\Bbb R\setminus\{1\} \to\Bbb R\ \ f(x)= \frac{x^2}{x-1}$$ is neither injective  nor subjective.

For the function to be non-injective I have to  disprove that $$f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2 \ \ or\ x_1\neq x_2\implies f(x_1)\neq f(x_2).$$
For $f(x)$ to be non surjective I have to find at leat one image that is not hit by a pre-image.

Can someone help me find these values and/or show how it is done properly?

Thank you!

Comment: Consider assigning $f(x)$ a value and showing how 2 different initial values produce the same result. Similarly, what kinds of values don't exist in the range of $f(x)$?

Comment: For injectivity, start with $f(x)= f(y)$, solve the quadratic equation for $y$ and see if you can find a $x$ such that $y \neq x$. For the surjectivity, let $f(x) =c$, solve the quadratic for $x$ and see if you can find $c$ such that the solution is not real, i.e. the square root is taken from a negative number.

Answer (score 3):

$f(-1)=f(\frac{1}{2})$ so $f$ is not injective

and $f(x)=2$ has no solution so $f$ is not surjective

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation
$$
f(x) = \frac {x^2}{x-1} = \alpha \implies x^2 - \alpha x + \alpha = 0
$$
and try to solve it. Obviously, if $D = \alpha^2 - 4\alpha < 0$ i.e. when $\alpha \in (0, 4)$, equation doesn't have a solution. So there are some $y \in Y$ that don't have a preimage in $X$. So $f:X \to Y$ is not surjective. Another conclusion you can draw just looking at $D$ is if $D > 0 \implies \alpha \in (-\infty, 0) \cup (4, +\infty)$, then your equation always has two distinct solutions, so $f(x)$ is not injective either.

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't the interval be  $$\alpha \in (0, 8)$$ for $$ D = \alpha^2 - 8\alpha < 0 $$ ?  $$D = b^2 - 4ac $$

Comment: @user108410 Sorry, I misread the problem. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the derivative and study the sign of it.
$f'(x)=\frac{x(x-2)}{(x-1)}$
to show that the function has only 2 extremas one local minimum $(x=2, y=4)$
and one local maximum $(x=0, y=0)$. You can study the limit in a  neighborhood of the vertical asymptote $x=1$ to see that you 
have two branches 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow <1} = -\infty$ 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow >1} = +\infty$ 
and finally the limits near the domain bounds 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} = -\infty$ 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} = +\infty$

Reminder: $f:E\rightarrow F$ is surjective $\iff f(E)=F$.

The image of your function is then $f(E=\mathbb R-\{1\})=(-\infty,0]\cup [4,\infty)$  which differs from its codomain $F=\mathbb R$, whence $f$ non-surjective.

Reminder $f$ is injective $\iff (f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y)$

Simply check if the relation holds for any two pre-images $x$ and $y$. $\frac{x^2}{x-1}=\frac{y^2}{y-1}\Rightarrow x^2(y-1)=y^2(x-1)$. Consider the equation as a polynomial with unknown $x$ and $y$ treated as a constant.
$(y-1) x^2 -y^2 x + y^2 =0$

When solving this 2 distinct solutions are obtained in the general case (do not pick-up any particular value for $y$)

$x=y$ or $x=\frac{2y}{y-1}$, hence $f$ is not injective.